# Javascript: Recursive Depth First Search for hierarchical reordering based on d3's recurse()

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, depth-first-search

I'm trying to do a depth first search through a complex JSON object such as [this one](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?indent=true&filter=%28all+name%3A%22Blade+Runner%22%29&output=%28disambiguator%29), and output a new object with a new structure of:

```
[
    {
       name: "Blade Runner",
       children : [
           {Obj}, {Obj},{Obj}, ...
       ]
     },
     ...
]
```

I've looked at d3.js's `recurse()` function as reference, but can't seem to wrap my head around how I would write a similar function given an input JSON without pre-existing "children" arrays:

```
function recurse(node, depth, nodes) {
  //assumes children exist in node object
  var childs = children.call(hierarchy, node, depth);
  node.depth = depth;
  nodes.push(node);
  if (childs && (n = childs.length)) {
    var i = -1, n, c = node.children = [], v = 0, j = depth + 1, d;
    while (++i < n) {
      d = recurse(childs[i], j, nodes);
      d.parent = node;
      c.push(d);
      v += d.value;
    }
    if (sort) c.sort(sort);
    if (value) node.value = v;
  } else if (value) {
    node.value = +value.call(hierarchy, node, depth) || 0;
  }
  return node;
}
```

How would you write a new function like this to do a DFS on the JSON response above?

Answer (score 0):

As commented, the criteria for the new structure you want to create is unclear. Though, DefiantJS (http://defiantjs.com) might help you to traverse JSON structure such as the one you've exemplified.

DefiantJS extends the global object with the method "search", with which you can search for matches in JSON structure, regardless of depth. The method returns an array of the matching elements (empty if no matches were found).

For example:
(working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hbi99/x6B3A/)

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?indent=true&filter=%28all+name%3A%22Blade+Runner%22%29&output=%28disambiguator%29';
Defiant.ajax(url)
    .search('//*[name="Musical Track"]')
    .each(function(item) {
        console.log( item );
    });
```

This code downloads the JSON structure and search for any elements named "Musical Track" and returns the two matches.